# DocumentClient.CreateDocument 'options'?

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to understand what options Azure's DocumentDb `DocumentClient.CreateDocument()` takes...

I've searched high and low and I just cannot find out what `options` are available.

Where have I looked?

1. [The documentation](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-python/api/pydocumentdb.document_client.html#pydocumentdb.document_client.DocumentClient.CreateDocument)
2. [The source](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-python/modules/pydocumentdb/document_client.html#DocumentClient.CreateDocument)
3. [The samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-python-samples)
4. [The 'Quick Start' example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-documentdb-python)
5. [The tests...](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-python/blob/master/test/crud_tests.py)

Answer (score 1):

Python documentation definitely seems to be a bit out of date. I imagine that the options are the same as what's [available in the JS version](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/Collection.html#.CreateOptions) though:

The properties available on the options object for creating a document are:

```
{
   indexAction: "default|include|exclude",
   disableAutomaticIdGeneration: "string"
}
```